# Remote Objects Query Criteria Where Condition "in"

Tags: query, javascript-remoting, remote-objects, criteria

I have an array list that takes many ids. I am trying to get records with remote objects according to array list. I am using 'in' condition for this scenario and ı am getting an error that is "Invalid criteria specified for retrieval. ValidationError [code=11, message=Data does not match any schemas from "oneOf", path=/where, schemaKey=null]"

How can I solve this problem?

```
var icd10Data = new SObjectModel.icd10();

var gemList = ["a0Oi0000008z8OPEAY", "a0Oi000000E9twVEAR", "a0Oi0000008z8OPEAY"];           
icd10Data.retrieve({ where:{in:{Id: gemList }  } }, function(err, records){                                                   
                                                         if(err) alert(err.message);
                                                         else {
                                                             populateIcd10(records);       
                                                          }
                                                     });               

}            

function populateIcd10(records) {
     records.forEach(function(record) {                 
         var toAddName = record.get("Name");
         var toAddId = record.get("Id");                 
         icd10ArrayList[toAddId] =toAddName;
      });  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [Format and Options for Remote Objects Query Criteria](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_retrieve_query_object.htm) documentation I think the first argument to the `retrieve` call should be:

```
{where: {Id: {in: gemlist}}}
```

However, it is important to note that you must also `unique` your array or you will get a similar error.